# VB.Net and C# Projects in 1 Solution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way for me to create multiple projects using different languages under 1 solution in VS 2008? If so, how?

Comment: While it would have been easier if the OP could just try it before asking, I don't think the question deserves a -1 vote. Voting up

Comment: Within Visual Studio EXPRESS EDITION this is NOT POSSIBLE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Oded says, you just create them.  Do this by right-clicking the `Solution` node, selecting `Add > New Project`, selecting the language and project type you want, and giving it a name.

The only times I know of when this doesn't work are:

1. When your `Always show solution` option is not checked (under `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions`)
2. When you don't have both languages installed, for example if you installed Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition without Visual C# 2008 Express Edition or vice versa, or if you deselected one of the languages during installation.  Note that except for the express edition, each edition contains all languages by default.

If you are having problems I would verify neither of the above problems applies.  Just check the `Tools > Options` setting and check the `Installed products` list under `Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio`.  If you need to change the `Installed products` list, just rerun VS.NET setup (or the appropriate Express edition setup).

Answer (score 8):

Just create them. A solution can happily hold projects of different languages. I have C# and VB.NET projects sitting in the same solution without a problem.

What you can't do is mix languages in the same *project*.

Comment: It is possible to mix languages in the same .NET assembly (by compiling different modules with different compilers). However, this scenario is not supported by the Visual Studio IDE, and is therefore pretty useless for all practical purposes.

Comment: If I recall correctly, in VS2002 when you right click the solution, there was an option to add a project of a different language. I don't see that in 2008.

I must be blind or something. I can't find that option now. Where do I go to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You will also need attribute "CLSCompliant" to ignore types/members which are not cls compliant.

For instance, if you are using C# and VB project, you will need to exclude methods with same signature but difference in case (VB is not case-sensitive)

```
        [CLSCompliant(false)]
        public static string GetTypeName() {
            return "SomeBase";
        }

        [CLSCompliant(false)]
        public static string getTypeName() {
            return "somBase";
        }
```

Comment: Interesting observation about the difference in case-sensitivity between C# and VB.NET, but I would hope any well-designed C# library would never actually need this. Giving two functions the same name differing only by case seems like bad practice to me, because it becomes very easy to confuse the two when calling them. Different names or a parameter explicitly specifying which type of string value to return would both make the code much clearer and avoid the VB.NET compatibility issue entirely.